# Checking in Files via AnkhSVN not prompting to enter FogBugz Case Number

Tags: tortoisesvn, fogbugz, ankhsvn

So I followed [the fogbugz guidelines](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/docs/40/Articles/SourceControl/TortoiseSVN.html) to add some properties to my project repository. The only SVN property I changed was bugtraq:warnifnoissue. In the documentation mentioned above, it's set to false. I set it to true. If I use TortoiseSVN, when I go to check in a file, I will see the Fogbugz case number textbox to the above right of the checkin comments textbox. If I check-in without putting a FogBugz case number it says something along the lines of "Are you sure you want to check in without specifying a case number?". I put this on to give a friendly nudge to developers to enter a case number. It's just a prompt, doesn't force a case number to be entered. This all works great.

However, in AnkhSVN, all the above works as described, with the SVN propeties I've set, but I do not get the friendly prompt. Is this just AnkhSVN not supporting prompts like TortoiseSVN or is there some AnkhSVN setting I need to set or an additional SVN property that needs to be set for AnkhSVN?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed that's the case. AnkhSVN does not support that property (yet). Feel free to suggest/vote for it at [uservoice](http://feedback.ankhsvn.net/forums/3267-general/suggestions/349677-support-the-bugtraq-warnifnoissue-svn-property)

Comment: Thanks Sander. I've posted a request here http://feedback.ankhsvn.net/pages/3267-general/suggestions/349677-support-the-bugtraq-warnifnoissue-svn-property

Comment: The latest version of AnkhSVN supports this now.